# Exception while inserting C# datatable into Access table - System.InvalidOperationException: Missing the DataColumn 'ID' for the SourceColumn 'ID'

Tags: c#, insert

I am getting the aforementioned exception when I am trying to insert all the rows from my table that has a primary key value on a string column "MedName", into an Access table that has an auto-incremented primary key. This is what I am doing:

```
OleDbConnection con;
OleDbCommand cmd;
OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
string Connection ="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+Directory;
con=new OleDbConnection(Connection);
string selectCommand = "select * from AccessTableTest";
cmd=new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(Query,con) ;
adapter=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
dt.PrimaryKey = null; //Tried to see if PK is causing trouble. No luck
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    dr.SetModified(); //Tried this. Helped me to insert for the very first time.
}
adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
var rows = adapter.Update(dt); //dt is the function parameter
con.Close();
```

SO, adapter.Update(dt) throws error "Missing the DataColumn 'ID' for the SourceColumn 'ID'"

Note: The very first insert command was successful with dr.SetModified() statement but all the subsequent inserts fail. I made sure that all columns of table match with those of access table.

Also, the insert command from adapter.InsertCommand looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO DrugAudit (Category, SubCategory, Quantity, MedName, OrderTrigger, Issues, Price, Notes, Summary, Recommendations, Alternative) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Please help. I have been trying to resolve this for couple of days now. Thanks!

Comment: Is you source and destination in the same access db ?

Comment: My source is a C# datatable and destination is the access table. Sorry if I did not get your question right. Thanks!

Comment: How is the data getting into your DataTable object?

Comment: From a winform - user input. I am saving all the form data into datatable object.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by simply looping through the table like this:

```
con.Open();
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
 string insertCommand = "Insert INTO DrugAudit (Category, SubCategory, Quantity, MedName, OrderTrigger, Issues, Price, Notes, Summary, Recommendations, Alternative) VALUES (";
//dr.SetModified();
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
    insertCommand += "'" + dr[dc].ToString() + "',"
}
int lastIndex = insertCommand.LastIndexOf(',');
insertCommand = insertCommand.Remove(lastIndex);
insertCommand += ");";
cmd=new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(insertCommand,con);
int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

But, I would still like to know why adapter.Update(dt) method which I first tried failed to insert table into the access table. Would really appreciate if anyone could point to what I was doing wrong in previous procedure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inserting the whole table failed, because one of the column names is a reserved keyword.

this requires to specify both QuotePrefix and QuoteSuffix on OleDbCommandBuilder.

For MS access, this is 
builder.QuotePrefix = "[";
builder.QuoteSuffix = "]";

set them before calling GetInsertCommand(), and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this similar issue with WinForm/Visual Basic/OleDB 7.0.0

> System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatingRowStatusErrors
> Missing the DataColumn 'ID' for the SourceColumn 'ID'.

I was using joined query:

> "Select * from Employee, Account where Employee.accID = Account.ID"

Error didn't happen with single table query at all.

Then I changed all the column names that are similar:

> Account.ID => Account.accID
> Employee.ID => Employee.empID
> Employee.accID => Employee.accountID

And the problem is gone. I assume that Access/OleDB were confused with similar column name when updating rows. So experience is using all different columns' name even in different tables.